# Calculate Invoice Date and Discount Date based on Custom Date field in Bills and Adjustments

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom date field 'Invoice Date' in Bills and Adjustments. In Bils and Adjustments, Due Date and Cash Discount Date calculated based on DocDate and selected TermsID.

But instead of DocDate, I would like to use the date from my custom field 'Invoice Date' for the calculation of Due Date and Cash Discount Date.

I tried searching for DocDate and TermsID's field updated event in the APInvoiceEntry graph and also tried to find the PXFormula attribute in CacheAttached for Due Date and Cash Discount date in the graph. Moreover, I also looked at APInvoice DAC to find the formula for Due Date and Cash Discount Date but couldn't find anywhere. I tried to find methods in DiscountEngine class as well, but no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Create a new attribute derived from TermsAttribute and rewrite
`CalcTerms` method. Replace attribute on `TermsID` field.

---

**Proper Answer**

The most robust way to understand the logic that updates some field is to use debugger. 
To do that can use the following steps:

1. Add event that you use for setting a breakpoint using a customization. In that case FieldUpdating is the best match.

> ```
> public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
> {
>     public void APInvoice_DueDate_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Publish the customization.
3. Open the code in Visual Studio

   A. If you use runtime code (built in code editor in customization project), go to `SiteFolder\App_RuntimeCode` and open the needed file in visual studio (administrator mode).

   B. If you use Extension library, open your Visual studio project (administrator mode)
4. Set a breakpoint to the event
5. Attach debugger. In Visual studio Menu go to `Debug` -> `Attach to process` -> attach to IIS process (usually the name is w3wp.exe) (make sure checkbox `Show processes from all users` is checked)
6. Trigger field update. In this case you can change Doc Date to trigger Due Date recalculation.
7. When breakpoint is hit, check the Call Stack Window[image]
8. You can navigate through call stack double clicking on rows. In that case `PX.Objects.dll!PX.Objects.CS.TermsAttribute.CalcTerms(PX.Data.PXCache sender, PX.Data.PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) Line 3461` looks promising.
9. Normally, you should see the code of everything that is in PX.Objects.dll, but if you don't see it, here are steps to fix it:

   - Make sure you set `Install debugger tools`when you install Acumatica ERP
   - Disable `Enable Just My Code` option in Visual Studio Settings
   - You can manually point visual studio to source code located in `SiteFolder\App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects`
10. Explore the code to find a best place to override the logic. In that case, the best way would be to create a new attribute derived from TermsAttribute and rewrite `CalcTerms` method (that way you will still be able to reuse base `CalcTermsDates` method)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. TermsAttribute.CalcTerms was the one I was looking for. 

In my case, I simply override the FieldUpdated of Terms and my custom field's FieldUpdated event and passed the new field's date in CalcTerms method and get the Due Date and Disc Date which I used to set values for corresponding fields.